# How can I filter only certain elements of an XML file and write to another XML file using a batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I recieve very long xml files containing so many lines that my editor can´t open them without crashing. I need to be able to filter the xml file so that certain tags are kept and written to another file. In other words, 99% of the contents need to be removed and the result saved somewhere else.

The parent element is called:

```
<TransferSatz_Wartung>
```

the child elements that need to kept are:

```
<Anlage_Allgemein>

<Anlage_Erlaubnis>

<Wartung_Probenahme>

<Wartung_Allgemein>
```

..so that after the script is run I want to see the following output:

```
<TransferSatz_Wartung>
<Anlage_Allgemein>
    <child node1></child node>
    <child node2></child node>
    <child node3></child node>
</Anlage_Allgemein>     
<Anlage_Erlaubnis>
    <child node1></child node>
    <child node2></child node>
    <child node3></child node>
</Anlage_Erlaubnis>     
<Wartung_Probenahme>
    <child node1></child node>
    <child node2></child node>
    <child node3></child node>
</Wartung_Probenahme>
<Wartung_Allgemein>
    <child node1></child node>
    <child node2></child node>
    <child node3></child node>
</Wartung_Allgemein>
<TransferSatz_Wartung>
```

This Sample code  underneath does not include all child tags but shows that the Parent node is called TransferListe and the children that I want to extract are all within this. The First Child that I want to keep is called Anlage_Allgemein and can be seen on line 4. All nodes inside this Tag should be kept.

```
<TransferListe>
    <TransferSatz_Wartung>
        <Version>4.06</Version>
        <Anlage_Allgemein>
            <IstAktiv>1</IstAktiv>
            <AnlagenNr>415</AnlagenNr>
            <VerfahrenBRAnzBehaelter>1</VerfahrenBRAnzBehaelter>
            <Strasse>Höremer Weg</Strasse>
            <HausNr>1</HausNr>
            <Laenderkennung>D-</Laenderkennung>
            <PLZ>29690</PLZ>
            <Ort>Hörem</Ort>
            <Ortsteil/>
            <Ansprechpartner/>
            <TelefonNr/>
            <Gemarkung/>
            <Flur/>
            <Flurstueck/>
            <Rechtswert>0000000</Rechtswert>
            <Hochwert>0000000</Hochwert>
            <DatumWartungsvertrag>17.06.1996</DatumWartungsvertrag>
            <AnlageAusgelegtEW>6</AnlageAusgelegtEW>
            <GesamtgroesseVK>0.0</GesamtgroesseVK>
            <DatumNaechsteWartung>07.06.2016</DatumNaechsteWartung>
            <Breitengrad>00°  00&#39;  00,0&#39;&#39;</Breitengrad>
            <Laengengrad>00°  00&#39;  00,0&#39;&#39;</Laengengrad>
        </Anlage_Allgemein>
        <Anlage_Erlaubnis>
            <DefBundeslaenderID>9</DefBundeslaenderID>
            <DefUWBID>31</DefUWBID>
            <AZ_UWB>66.601/66-32-159-042</AZ_UWB>
            <ErlaubnisNr>159-042</ErlaubnisNr>
            <DatumEinlErlaubnis>01.01.2001</DatumEinlErlaubnis>
            <ErlBefristungErlaubnis>01.01.2001</ErlBefristungErlaubnis>
            <ErlDatumGenehmigung>01.01.2001</ErlDatumGenehmigung>
            <ErlBefristungGenehmigung>01.01.2001</ErlBefristungGenehmigung>
            <ErlDatumInbetriebnahme>01.01.2001</ErlDatumInbetriebnahme>
            <ErlDatumAbnahme>01.01.2000</ErlDatumAbnahme>
            <Wartungshaeufigkeit>1</Wartungshaeufigkeit>
            <Eigenwartung>0</Eigenwartung>
            <Wartungsvertrag>1</Wartungsvertrag>
            <ErlGefordReinigungsklasse>0</ErlGefordReinigungsklasse>
            <ErlZusReinigungsklasse>0</ErlZusReinigungsklasse>
        </Anlage_Erlaubnis>
```

Comment: Batch don't know where do the child elements end, so pls explain how parent and child elements look in xml code (not familiar with xml btw..)

Comment: You should have to create a custom executable program to be called from inside your batch file, which language are you handy with? c#?

Comment: I could maybe do some scripting with Python?

Comment: Please refer to the edited question

Comment: It's quite simple, use `for /f` or [jrepl.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044)

Comment: Psh.  Tokenizing and scraping XML as flat text = fail.  Parsing XML as XML = win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See whether this PowerShell script does what you want.  Save it with a .ps1 extension.

```
[xml]$xml = gc XMLfile.xml
$keep = @(
    'Anlage_Allgemein',
    'Anlage_Erlaubnis',
    'Wartung_Probenahme',
    'Wartung_Allgemein'
)
$XPath = "//TransferSatz_Wartung/*[not(self::" + ($keep -join " or self::") + ")]"

$xml.SelectNodes($XPath) | %{
    $_.parentNode.removeChild($_)
}

$xml.save("output.xml")
```

From a cmd prompt or batch script, run it with the following syntax:

```
powershell ".\scriptname.ps1"
```